# spring cloud config server concurrency control

Tags: spring-cloud

I've multiple consuming app instances connecting to spring cloud config server. Config server gets config from SVN Repo.

Just wanted to understand how config server (instance) is managing possibly concurrent requests.

Thanx,

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug in the SVN support (the git version has a synchronized method). https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/128